# Self referencing entity CRUD EF CORE

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, crud

I have trouble to do a CRUD for self reference entity.

This is my entity:

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; } = new HashSet<Recipe>();
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Parent { get;set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; } = new HashSet<Category>();
}
```

ModelBuilder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
    .WithMany(c => c.Categories)
    .HasOne(c => c.Parent)
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId);
```

My create logic:

```
public void Save(Category category)
{
    if(category.Parent != null && category.Parent.Id == 0)
    {
       category.Parent = null;
    }
    else
    {
        _db.Entry(category.Parent).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    }
    _db.Category.Add(category);
    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Update logic:

```
public void Update(Category category)
{
    _db.Category.Update(category);
    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

`CategoryDto` class:

```
public class CategoryDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public CategoryDto Parent { get; set; }
}
```

I am not able to save this `object` to database, because seems like `Parent` wants to be saved as well, getting that `Name` field is required.

Any ideas how CRUD should look like for a self referencing entity?

Any answers are appreciated.

Comment: did u remove circular reference in startup.cs?

Comment: I have already that.

Comment: it looks your same class act as Primary key table and Foreign key table also

Comment: Yes, but is there anyway to achieve this kind of solution without key relationships ?

Comment: is you want `Has/With` relationship in same model that act as pk and fk also?

Comment: Yes, i want that category would have PK and FK to its parent.

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure the serializer to ignore circular references in your project.

So for this you have to add following line of code inside `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs`

Like

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => {
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    });
}
```

After adding this line of codes you will be able to insert records in table with have circular reference.

Answer (score 0):

Edited question how everything should look like that Create/Update for reference entity would work.